# Any possibility to declare indexers in C# as an abstract member?

Tags: c#, abstract, indexer

As the title states, I would like to declare an indexer `object this[int index]` in an abstract class as an abstract member.

Is this possible in any way? Is it possible to declare this in an interface too?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Of course](http://ycouriel.blogspot.com/2009/10/c-abstract-index-operator.html):

```
public abstract class ClassWithAbstractIndexer 
{
    public abstract int this[int index]
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried `public abstract object this[int index];` then `public object this[int index] { abstract get; }` but none of them worked. How is it declared in an interface?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: Remove `abstract` from your `get` in your derived class.

Comment: `public` is not valid in an interface, as all interface members are implicitly `public`.

Comment: This is not an interface - but part of an abstract class decleration

Answer (score 2):

A simple example:

```
public interface ITest
{
    int this[int index] { get;  }
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { ... }
        private set { .... }
    }
}
```

Several combinations of private/protected/abstract are possible for `get` and `set`

Answer (score 0):

You may declare it like this:

```
internal abstract class Hello
{
  public abstract int Indexer[int index]
  {
      get;
  }
}
```

Then you'll have the option to override only `get` or override both `get` and `set`.

Comment: This does not compile.